# string.Format paste string as parameter without quotes

Tags: c#, .net, string, string-formatting, interpolation

I am formatting a string:

```
string.Format(
            "{{\"EventType\":\"{0}\",\"OrganizationId\":\"{1}\",\"Timestamp\":{2},\"ExecutionTime\":{3},\"Success\":{4}}}",
            telemetryEvent.EventType ?? "null", telemetryEvent.OrganizationId ?? "null", telemetryEvent.Timestamp,
            telemetryEvent.ExecutionTime, telemetryEvent.Success);
```

I need to get null instead of string if it is null.

E.g. ""OrganizationId":null"
but I get ""OrganizationId":"null"" instead

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you are attempting to create a JSON representation of the `telemetryEvent` instance. Why not use [`Json.Net`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for that?

Comment: @ZoharPeled can't use any libs, not allowed(

Comment: Well, simple solution would be remove the escape quotes

Comment: Move quotes to the argument, not the format string? It's not optimal but it would work

Comment: What do you mean "can't use any libs"? Json serializing is built into .NET. Granted, it is not as good as Json.net but it is probably good enough to do what you need. Have you looked into using it instead?

Comment: If you cant use third party libraries you can try `DataContractJsonSerializer` in `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json`. Not sure if the framework you are using comes with this built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest solution would probably be to use `replace`:

```
string.Format(
        "{{\"EventType\":\"{0}\",\"OrganizationId\":\"{1}\",\"Timestamp\":{2},\"ExecutionTime\":{3},\"Success\":{4}}}",
        telemetryEvent.EventType ?? "null", telemetryEvent.OrganizationId ?? "null", telemetryEvent.Timestamp,
        telemetryEvent.ExecutionTime, telemetryEvent.Success)
    .Replace("\"null\"", "null");
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/QUIG79340)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting "null", because the quotes are already added by the string template:

```
"{{\"EventType\":\"{0}\"
  ,\"OrganizationId\":\"{1}\",...
```

**So whatever you put in {0} and {1}, it will be put within the double quotes.**

In order to get rid of them, add quotes around the variables themselves.

**Update:** Sorry, my previous version was not correct (thanks Zohar for spotting this). The approach is valid but you need to use a ternary expression instead of a null coalescing operator:

```
"{{\"EventType\":{0},\"OrganizationId\":{1},...
  ,telemetryEvent.EventType != null ? "\"" + telemetryEvent.EventType + "\"" : "null"
  ,telemetryEvent.OrganizationId != null ? "\"" + telemetryEvent.OrganizationId + "\"" : "null",...
```

It becomes "a bit" cumbersome like this though so there are probably better approaches.

Maybe you already know, but this kind of string building gets more readable by using string interpolation (cf. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).

Comment: `"\"" + telemetryEvent.EventType + "\""` will never be null... if `telemetryEvent.EventType` is null it will simply be a string containing `""`.

Comment: Yeah okay, but my response applies to all parameters (telemetryEvent.EventType,  telemetryEvent.OrganizationId,...).
I will clarify my answer.

Comment: Yeah, well, the point of my comment is that using the `??` operator on `"\"" + telemetryEvent.EventType + "\""` is useless since it will never be null...

Comment: Ah dammit... you are right. I'm sorry, I wasn't thinking.

Comment: Updated my answer with a ternary expression. Not very readable like this though.

Comment: Yeah, that would work. But as you said, not very readable (and you have to repeat it for each variable). That's why I've suggested the `replace` - it's simple, quick, readable and you only need to write it once.

Answer (score 0):

You've got quotes around {1}, so the quotes will always appear in the output. 
Move them into the value for parameter 1.

```
string.Format(
        "{{\"EventType\":\"{0}\",\"OrganizationId\":{1},\"Timestamp\":{2},\"ExecutionTime\":{3},\"Success\":{4}}}",
        telemetryEvent.EventType ?? "null", 
        telemetryEvent.OrganizationId ?? "null", "\"" + telemetryEvent.Timestamp + "\"",
        telemetryEvent.ExecutionTime, telemetryEvent.Success);
```